# Earth-Sun decayed L1 to L4 transfer

Tags: delta-v, lagrangian-points, three-body

Assume CR3BP (Circular Restricted 3-Body Problem) where a satellite occupies the Earth-Sun L<sub>1</sub> point. The satellite dies, stops station-keeping, experiences a small perturbation (minimal effect on Jacobi), then decays for some arbitrary time `t`. What is the delta-v budget and travel time for Earth to rescue the satellite to L<sub>4</sub>? This can be split into two cases: sunward decay, and earthward decay.

(Most of the literature I've found discusses Earth-Lagrange transfers, not Lagrange-Lagrange, let alone after decay. I suspect the only solution is to simulate, sampling random `t`, but there may be more analytical insight I don't know.)

Comment: I just wrote an answer to how to recover back to the original orbit then deleted it when I re-read the question. This is much more interesting!

Comment: That could be a weak solution, just take the long route: decay->L1->LEO->L4. An upper bound on the problem, but I was hoping for the direct route. I didn't ask for the most minimal delta-v solution, since I'm sure chaos theorists could optimise the direct route and add a century or two to the travel time, but I would like a <10yr travel time.